# What is the correct way to back up an Oracle 11g database with 190GB of data

Tags: backup, oracle-11g

Right now we are doing the following:

1. Generating a DMP file to a windows
   server, this takes about 14hrs
2. Copy the DMP file to tape, this
   takes about 10 hrs
3. Archive it.....

In total this takes about 24hrs to do this. Any ideas would be appreciated.....

Comment: The DMP generation - is it over a net connection?  Even comparing to gigabit, creating the file locally & moving it afterwards should be faster...  Anyway, better luck to you on Serverfault: http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 2):

Look into RMAN, there's a lot to it, but it will do your backups in minutes, not days.